# Symfony Messenger Undefined constant SIGTERM

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger, symfony-cli

I have a problem with Symfony messenger, I have installed the redis extension, Symfony Messenger Redis package and the problem occurs when the command "php bin/console messenger:consume async" is executed and an error is generated " php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "SIGTERM"", transport and routing are already configured.

file: config/packages/messenger.yaml

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        routing:
            App\Message\SendMailMessage: async
```

[image]

The redis extension is already installed.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

*Installed packages*

Symfony v6.3.3
Symfony/Messenger v6.3.2
Symfony/Redis-Messenger v6.3.5

**PHP 8.2.8**

I have uninstalled the packages and installed them again and the problem still occurs, the transports and messenger routes have been configured, but it still does not work.

Comment: Does your PHP environment have the `pcntl` extension installed and enabled?

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to have `pcntl` extension installed and enabled in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Same error here, after upgrade symfony/messenger from v6.3.3 to v6.3.5 (or any other related package?), no Symfony/Redis-Messenger. Adding `pcntl` helps - just such dependency should be better documented/required by composer? :-(

Comment: This regression happened in a patch release!?

Comment: I was not looking for details, but probably yes - the first error `Undefined constant "SIGTERM"` appeared after upgrade to 6.3.5 (and this upgrade was together with forced upgrade of symfony/amqp-messenger to 6.3.4 which fixes another bug with amqp php extension which meantime has got a new major version, see https://github.com/symfony/amqp-messenger/commit/24e5cc90da041e0e1b7bbe15b82ad7f27a508c01)